# File Uploading MVC3 and Microsoft Web Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am currently using the file upload helper that comes with Microsoft.WebHelpers like this

```
@FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles: 1, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: true, includeFormTag: false, uploadText: "Upload")
```

This correctly gives me a upload box but I am having two problems with this that I cannot seem to find an answer for.

The first problem is the box does not display the filename correctly if I have a long path.

The second problem is that I can add a bunch of new files but there does not seem to be a remove option that can be turned on.

I need to find a good tool to facilitate file uploads that will give me these options and seamlessly integrate with asp.net mvc3 or figure out a way to do this with the upload tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what current tools are as far  as nuGet packages go.  However, I know that you can roll your own pretty easily.

In view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
...
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" size="60" /><input type="button">
...
<input type="submit">
}
<script>function(){ //make button add another input field with id="files"}
</script>
```

Note: new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } is required to send files to the controller from a form.

In Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    foreach(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile in files)
    {
         //work with uploadFile
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically what the fileupload control gives you. It does not seem to allow you to modify the size of the field with the filename and does not give a remove option.

Comment: Do you mean modifying the size of the field after the file is chosen?  For the most part, all of the work that is going to be done after the page is rendered will be in javascript, ajax, or jquery.  This is where you would need to write code to manage dynamic resizing of the field size or removing selected files for uploading.